# jQuery Find Selector Not Selecting Array Item

Tags: jquery

I'm in the process of trying to access a list of photos using the jQuery find selector, but for some reason it does not appear to be working.  I'm using jQuery 1.8.

Ideal code:

```
$(this).siblings(images_container).find(photo);
```

Current Code:

```
$(this).siblings(images_container).children().find(".photo");
```

The current code doesn't work either.  Selecting the children like:

```
$(this).siblings(images_container).children()
```

album_id_3 is $this

HTML

```
<div class="photo_wrap">
  <a href="#" id="album_id_3">
    <div class="photo_img_wrap">
      <img src="/assets/img/user_images/2_4.jpg">
      <div class="album_photo_count">
        1
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <div class="album_name">
    Untitled
  </div>
  <div style="display: none;" class="images_container">
    <div class="album_description_hidden">
      test
    </div>
    <div class="city_id">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="photo">
      <div class="desc">
      </div>
      <div class="image_id">
        4
      </div>
      <div class="name">
        /assets/img/user_images/2_4.jpg
      </div>
      <div class="status">
         1
      </div>
      <div class="time">
        1363005386
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Returns

```
jQuery(div.album_description_hidden, div.city_id, div.photo)
```

But when I try to add find to it to specifically only grab elements with ".photo" jQuery is returning empty. Do you know why?

Comment: please post a sample of your HTML structure, otherwise we really cannot tell what should or should not work.

Comment: Try this: 
$(this).siblings(".images_container").children().find(".photo");

Answer (score 1):

This is because `.find()` only finds within children of the element you are searching on. Therefore as div.photo is one of the elements you are searching on, this won't be in the results

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching for div.photo that is the children of images container then you can do:

```
$(this).siblings(images_container).children('div.photo')
```

No need to use `find()`.

### Update

I think you missed class in images_container:

```
  $(this).siblings(".images_container").children('div.photo')
```

Or you can just do:

```
 $(this).parent().find('div.photo'); //parent takes you to `photo_wrap` and find will search `div.photo` inside photo_wrap which it will find
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like:

```
$(".photo", $(this).parent())
```

The jQuery function can be passed a second argument that is a Dom Element, or selector to find element below.

Answer (score 0):

From jQuery API documentation ::

> Description: Get the descendants of each element in the current set of
>   matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

so using your code you get the right children of your images container then you search inside them using `.photo`..You should make your filter on the children themselves not inside them.